# Find char newline at the end of closing tag </tag> using regx php

Tags: php, xml, regex

The xml file that I got from user may contain the newline character or may not.

So to be  usable xml format I have the solution to do by using regex

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd">
        <tag1>/* .. more .. */</tag1> /*newline*/
    </Document>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do with regex to recognize the xml string there is the newline character at the end of closing `</tag>`

**this approach allow me to more control the xml format and display message back to user.something like your xml file contain newline at the end of closing tag**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
</[^<]*>(?:\r?\n|\r\n?)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vd8i)

I am not sure if it is useful, but this is what its doing:

It searches for a closing tag `</[^<]*>`, followed by `\r?\n` or `\r\n?` where the `?` means the character before is optional.

Comment: yes it look good result,you mean like this in php:  preg_match("</[^<]*>(?:\r?\n|\r\n?)", $xml_str, $matches);

Comment: and when I try with php => preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending matching delimiter '>'

Answer (score 1):

Well-formed XML doesn't take into account newlines.  A newline isn't a part of the XML structure. `<foo><bar></bar></foo>` is the same as:

```
<foo>
    <bar>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

Consider looking at something like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for your parsing.

Comment: yes it does not matter ,but this approach allow me to more  control the xml format and display message back to user.some like your xml file contain newline at the end of closing tag .thanks